# Как подключить и настроить ML.Net к бд MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, ml.net

Я хочу построить график скачков или прогнозирования продаж используя данные таблицы БД MySQL.
Набрав в интернете как сделать с БД MySQL понял ,что надо скачать MySQLConnector и пробывать этот код

```
var source = new DatabaseSource(MySqlConnectorFactory.Instance,
    "server=myserver;user=myuser;password=pass",
    "select `Text`, Label from table");
var ctx = new MLContext();
var loader = ctx.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader(
    new("Text", DbType.String, 0),
    new("Label", DbType.Boolean, 1));
var view = loader.Load(source);
```

Только я толком не понял как и что здесь заменить и подставить и как отобразить результат

```
  "select `Text`, Label from table");
var loader = ctx.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader(
    new("Text", DbType.String, 0),
    new("Label", DbType.Boolean, 1));
```

Помогите пожалуйста настроить ML.Net к бд MySQL и отобразить как то,обьясните кто знает что нужно заменить в этом коде